# Bundler option not showing under tools in RubyMine

Tags: rubymine

[image]

I don't see the Bundler option under the Tools menu in RubyMine.

Comment: What version of RubyMine? If the rubymine-7 tag is correct, you're using a really old version.

Comment: @Dave Schweisguth - It's the latest, the tag name is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

It means that bundler is not installed in the current gemset.

Check that the same gemset is being used in RubyMine and in the bash console:

`$ rvm gemset name` , if you're using rvm

and the install bundler:

`$ gem install bundler`